# Postgres concatenating/aggregating a jsonb values into one string

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, string-aggregation

I have a table `entities` with a `jsonb` column `dict` which holds the locales as described below:

```
{
  "fr": {
    "key1": "french1",
    "key2": "french2"
  },
  "en": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
}
```

In the same table I have created a new `tsvector` column `en_locale` which need to hold the tsvector of the concatenation of the `dict -> 'en'` values.

for the example above I would like to achieve the following which is the concatenation of the values (order doesn't need to be preserved):

`value1 value2 value3` values are separated by spaces.

this is in order to populate the `tsvector` column `to_tsvector('value1 value2 value3')`

Any advice would be great! Thank you very much!

Comment: As far as I can tell `to_tsvector(dict -> 'en')` would only include the values as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dcc0ca2160572cee6406865a93e8a5fc (Btw: I think the duplicated `key2` is a typo, right?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, but as I'm using Postgresql 9.6 to ```to_tsvector(cfg, jsonb)``` is not supported :(

Comment: Then it's time to upgrade ;) Better support for full text search on JSONB columns, was included in Postgres 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not clear what exactly you want. Just based on your question's `TITLE` you want to concatenate the values of all keys in `dict -> 'en'`.

So try this:

```
select 
(select string_agg(j.value, ' ') 
from jsonb_each_text(dict->'en') j) "values" from your_table
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=19de6dbe9dbd62fc63a7bde73e29fe38)